# No VC/inc folder in my MSVS 2013 directory

Tags: addition, fltk

I'm trying to add FLTK to MSVS 2013 and I'm copying the .lib files into vc/inc but I cannot find the folder anywhere. Under the Visual Studio 2013 folder all I have is

```
ArchitectureExplorer, Backup Files, Code Snippets, 

Projects, Settings, StartPages, Templates, Visualizers
```

What am I missing here? I'm sure its something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by holder.  Start VS, select Tools/Options/Projects & Solutions/VC++ directories.

On the right pane, select Include files from the top right box and add your FLTK include directory in the listbox below.

Then select Library files from the top right box and add your FLTK library directory to the listbox below.

That's basically it - there is no need to copy files anywhere.

Comment: It's been deprecated in MSVS 2013 I guess. Whenever I go there it doesn't allow me to do anything.This is the guide I was following. http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html#W01_0020_downloading_fltk

Comment: The c-jump.com method isn't very suitable unless you have admin access.  also if there is a name clash (like math.h), it really messes up your VS installation.  If you use the method I have specified, you can set the priorities by moving the directories higher up or lower down the list.